# ghost.py + всплывающие окна

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется динамическая веб страница вся в `js`, на ней "ссылка", которая изменяет страницу, в `html` вылядит так -

```
<a href="#" class="no_link div_link" style="display: inline; " title="изменить">Изменить</a>
```

При клике на неё сперва появляется всплывающее окошко, с просьбой подтвердить действие, на котором две кнопки "ok" и "отменить".
Нажать на "ссылку" пытаюсь следующим образом -

```
session.evaluate("document.getElementsByClassName('no_link div_link').click();", expect_loading=True)
```

что приводит к ошибке

```
TimeoutError: Unable to load requested page
```

Как с помощью `ghost` отловить это всплывающее окно и нажать "Ok"?